# Why is Common Lisp's print output preceeded by a newline and followed by a space?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

[The Common Lisp Hyperspec page for `print`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_wr_pr.htm) mentions this:

> print is just like prin1 except that the printed representation of object is preceded by a newline and followed by a space.

This is the first time I've seen a function like this, and it threw me off the first time I used it, because I never expected that a function with such a common name might include an uncommon feature.

I'm looking for the original reason. I know it might simply be because that's how another then-common lisp might have done it, and common-lisp simply adopted it, but if that's the case I'm looking for the design reason in that *other* lisp.

I imagine it might have something to do with ensuring that the output is always readable with `read` straight out of `print`. Though I would've preferred a newline for this, I can guess that the trailing space might be so that in a stream, `read` can know that it's the end of an object and return it immediately without having to wait for the rest of the stream (the following `print`s). However, I still can't figure out the purpose behind the preceeding newline.

I've been looking through the HyperSpec, but I can't find a reason mentioned.

EDIT:

I looked into Common-Lisp's predecessors, specifically InterLisp, MacLisp, and MacLisp's predecessor Lisp 1.5.

Interlisp's (page 145 in [this pdf](http://bitsavers.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/pdf/xerox/interlisp/Interlisp_Reference_Manual_Oct_1983.pdf)) and Lisp 1.5's (page 140 in [this pdf](http://www.softwarepreservation.org/projects/LISP/book/Weismann_LISP1.5_Primer_1967.pdf)) `print` function print the object followed by a newline.

It seems it was MacLisp that introduced this difference. I didn't find a reason in the original reference manual, and I only found the following [on this revised reference manual](http://maclisp.info/pitmanual/io.html):

> Like PRIN1, PRINT outputs object to file in a form that can be understood by READ. However, object is output preceded by newline and followed by a space so that repeated calls to PRINT can be done without having the end of one object run into the begining of the next.

Of course, the trailing newline in the original definition would've sufficed for that purpose, so this reason doesn't seem valid.

EDIT 2:

As shown by Rainer Joswig's answer, it seems that this change appeared in Lisp 1.6 before MacLisp.

Comment: I'm just guessing, but I'd hazard to say that the leading newline is simply a variant on a trailing newline (one standard is arguably just as good as the other); and that the trailing space is because when `print` was first written, you'd want to move the print-head of the mechanical TTY out of the way so that you could see what was written.

Comment: @Dolda2000 After looking into CL's predecessors and finding that originally `print` _did_ simply output a trailing newline in Lisp 1.5, this seems unlikely.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See for example: [PDP-6 LISP (LISP 1.6) Revised. (January 1967)](http://www.softwarepreservation.org/projects/LISP/MIT/AIM-116A-White-Interim_User_Guide.pdf)

My guess would be that this variant of `PRINT` (which writes a newline, then the s-expression in readable format and then a space) entered the MIT branch of Lisp because of its use in the Read Eval Print Loop. See page 1 and 17 of above. From PDP-6 Lisp 1.6 it moved into what was then called Maclisp and beyond.

Jon L White would know it.

Look at the example for the REPL, the *read eval PRINT loop*, on page 1.
Here I use a LispWorks Lisp listener, where the last closing parenthesis already makes `READ` accept the *s-expression* and no further *enter* is necessary:

```
CL-USER 25 > (PROG NIL
               A
               (TERPRI)
               (PRINT (EVAL (READ)))
               (GO A))

(+ 12 12)
24 
(+ 45 (*
       34
       12
       12))
4941
```

Each result is on its own line. This is btw. also like the interaction on a MIT Lisp Machine - the last closing parenthesis enters the s-expression, the expression is evaluated and the value(s) printed.

Now imagine that it is defined to not print a newline first:

```
CL-USER 27 > (PROG NIL
               A
               (TERPRI)
               (PRIN1 (EVAL (READ)))
               (terpri)
               (GO A))

(+ 1 2)3

(* 23 (+ 1
         1
         3))115
```

The result would be printed directly after the last closing parenthesis.

Peter Norvig gives the same reasoning in his book *Paradigms of Artificial Intelligence Programming*, page 231/232 (as noted by user dkim):

> In Lisp, however, the function print puts in a newline before the object to be printed, and a space after. ... In UNIX there was only one reasonable policy, because all input to the UNIX interpreter (the shell) is terminated by newlines, so there is no need for a newline-before. In some Lisp interpreters, however, input can be terminated by a matching right parenthesis. In that case, a newline-before is needed, lest the output appear on the same line as the input.

Comment: This shows that indeed this change was in Lisp 1.6 before MacLisp, but neither this answer nor the pages you reference seem to mention the design reason, which is what I was looking for.

Comment: @jimg: see at the repl example from page 1, expanded in my answer.

Comment: "result would be printed directly after the last closing parenthesis" That doesn't happen with me, because terminal input is, by default, line buffered. I'd have to press `^D` after the closing parenthesis to get the result you're seeing, but the natural thing is to hit Enter, and so the result would be printed in the next line.

Comment: Quoted from PAIP: "In Lisp, however, the function `print` puts in a newline before the object to be printed, and a space after. ... In UNIX there was only one reasonable policy, because all input to the UNIX interpreter (the shell) is terminated by newlines, so there is no need for a newline-before. In some Lisp interpreters, however, input can be terminated by a matching right parenthesis. In that case, a newline-before is needed, lest the output appear on the same line as the input."

Comment: @jimg: you are using a Unix terminal. My example was from a LispWorks listener window, which is not terminal-based. Other Lisp systems also read Lisp expressions under Lisp control. For example in the REPL of a MIT Lisp Machine, the last closing parenthesis enters the expression, too.

Comment: "last closing parenthesis enters the expression" so this behaviour was done to the benefit of systems that don't do line buffering. This is also supported with dkim's reference to PAIP. I believe _that_ is the reason I was seeking. Think you can add that and dkim's reference to your answer? I'll accept it then.

Comment: @jimg: not only they don't do line-buffering, but they also may check/parse the s-expression syntax while you type the characters into the reader.

Comment: Seems like a different experience. I guess that if you mistype something you won't get the chace to hit Backspace and correct yourself and the reader will immediately tell you what you did wrong on hitting that one wrong character. However, I imagine there are benefits I'm not seeing.

Comment: @jlmg The listener tells you you've got something wrong, *and then* you get to delete characters and fix it up, at which point it will reparse the edited input.  Essentially the listener is constantly aware of the current state of the input and it knows if it could make sense.  These were very sophisticated readers!

Answer (score 2):

Basically this is a REPL-only function, something along the lines of "poor man's [`trace`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_tracec.htm) or [`debug`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/d_optimi.htm)".

It's use case is something like

```
(map nil #'print list)
```

or, more generally,

```
(complex-traversal-map #'print weird-structure)
```

It inserts whitespace around the printed object to avoid interference
with the output of other [`print`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_wr_pr.htm) calls.
What kind of whitespace is emitted has evolved over the decades.
It should have been called `print-on-a-separate-line` but it had to be
short and easily guessable.

It's essentially "legacy" functionality, like [`rplaca` and `rplacd`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_rplaca.htm).

Comment: Sounds reasonable and this is probably what it's most useful for. If you happen to have a source on hand, that'd be great to mention, but I realize that an official reason might not be mentioned anywhere. Anyway, I'll accept this answer tomorrow, unless a better answer appears by then.